# Android subscription purchase AccountHold is null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using official google example code for user subscription [play-billing-sample](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples). I get nullpointexception on checking the account hold when switching google accounts (my phone has two google accounts registered as test accounts to test the purchases).

1. I log into the first account without any problems and purchase basic or premium subscriptions
2. when I switch to the second account, I get the error below:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference at com.pishimishi.test.classytaxijava.billing.BillingUtilities.isAccountHold(BillingUtilities.java:151)`

BillingUtilities.java:

```
/**
     * Returns true if account hold should be shown.
     */
    public static boolean isAccountHold(SubscriptionStatus subscription) {
        return subscription != null &&
                !subscription.isEntitlementActive &&
                subscription.isAccountHold &&
                !subscription.subAlreadyOwned;
    }
```

and SubscriptionStatus.java:

```
/**
 * Local subscription data. This is stored on disk in a database.
 */
@Entity(tableName = "subscriptions")
public class SubscriptionStatus {
    public class SubscriptionStatusList {
        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("subscriptions")
        List<SubscriptionStatus> subscriptionStatuses;

        SubscriptionStatusList(@Nullable List<SubscriptionStatus> subscriptionStatuses) {
            this.subscriptionStatuses = subscriptionStatuses;
        }
    }

    public static final String SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY = "subscriptions";
    public static final String SKU_KEY = "sku";
    public static final String PURCHASE_TOKEN_KEY = "purchaseToken";
    public static final String IS_ENTITLEMENT_ACTIVE_KEY = "isEntitlementActive";
    public static final String WILL_RENEW_KEY = "willRenew";
    public static final String ACTIVE_UNTIL_MILLISEC_KEY = "activeUntilMillisec";
    public static final String IS_FREE_TRIAL_KEY = "isFreeTrial";
    public static final String IS_GRACE_PERIOD_KEY = "isGracePeriod";
    public static final String IS_ACCOUNT_HOLD_KEY = "isAccountHold";

    // Local fields
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int primaryKey = 0;
    @Nullable
    public String subscriptionStatusJson;
    public boolean subAlreadyOwned;
    public boolean isLocalPurchase;

    // Remote fields
    @Nullable
    public String sku;
    @Nullable
    public String purchaseToken;
    public Boolean isEntitlementActive;
    public Boolean willRenew;
    public Long activeUntilMillisec = 0L;
    public Boolean isFreeTrial;
    public Boolean isGracePeriod;
    public Boolean isAccountHold;

    /**
     * Parse subscription data from Map and return null if data is not valid.
     */
    @Nullable
    public static List<SubscriptionStatus> listFromMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
        List<SubscriptionStatus> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Map<String, Object>> subList = null;

        if (map.get(SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY) instanceof ArrayList) {
            subList = (ArrayList) map.get(SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY);
        }

        if (subList == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for (Map<String, Object> subStatus : subList) {
            SubscriptionStatus subscriptionStatus = new SubscriptionStatus();

            subscriptionStatus.sku = (String) subStatus.get(SKU_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.purchaseToken = (String) subStatus.get(PURCHASE_TOKEN_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.isEntitlementActive =
                    (Boolean) subStatus.get(IS_ENTITLEMENT_ACTIVE_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.willRenew = (Boolean) subStatus.get(WILL_RENEW_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.activeUntilMillisec =
                    (Long) subStatus.get(ACTIVE_UNTIL_MILLISEC_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.isFreeTrial = (Boolean) subStatus.get(IS_FREE_TRIAL_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.isGracePeriod = (Boolean) subStatus.get(IS_GRACE_PERIOD_KEY);
            subscriptionStatus.isAccountHold = (Boolean) subStatus.get(IS_ACCOUNT_HOLD_KEY);

            subscriptions.add(subscriptionStatus);
        }

        return subscriptions;
    }

    /**
     * Parse subscription data from String and return null if data is not valid.
     */
    @Nullable
    public static List<SubscriptionStatus> listFromJsonString(String dataString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            SubscriptionStatusList subscriptionStatusList =
                    gson.fromJson(dataString, SubscriptionStatusList.class);
            if (subscriptionStatusList != null) {
                return subscriptionStatusList.subscriptionStatuses;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a record for a subscription that is already owned by a different user.
     *
     * The server does not return JSON for a subscription that is already owned by
     * a different user, so we need to construct a local record with the basic fields.
     */
    public static SubscriptionStatus alreadyOwnedSubscription(String sku, String purchaseToken) {
        SubscriptionStatus subscriptionStatus = new SubscriptionStatus();
        subscriptionStatus.sku = sku;
        subscriptionStatus.purchaseToken = purchaseToken;
        subscriptionStatus.isEntitlementActive = false;
        subscriptionStatus.subAlreadyOwned = true;
        return subscriptionStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubscriptionStatus{" +
                "primaryKey=" + primaryKey +
                ", subscriptionStatusJson='" + subscriptionStatusJson + '\'' +
                ", subAlreadyOwned=" + subAlreadyOwned +
                ", isLocalPurchase=" + isLocalPurchase +
                ", sku='" + sku + '\'' +
                ", purchaseToken='" + purchaseToken + '\'' +
                ", isEntitlementActive=" + isEntitlementActive +
                ", willRenew=" + willRenew +
                ", activeUntilMillisec=" + activeUntilMillisec +
                ", isFreeTrial=" + isFreeTrial +
                ", isGracePeriod=" + isGracePeriod +
                ", isAccountHold=" + isAccountHold +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I don't understand it why I have to get NPE. Or if we get if from the server, why don't I get it with the first account (I even tested putting the purchase on pause for the first account) and it works.

PS. Initially in my play console, Account hold feature was not active, but later on, I activated the account hold and account pause feature. But still I get the same error just after switching to the second google account.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when Java uses `Boolean` object in **if statement** it unwraps it to primitive which is `boolean` type with `Boolean.booleanValue()` method.

To fix the issue you have to change `isAccountHold` and `isEntitlementActive` types from **Boolean** to **boolean**.
If those fields have to be **Boolean** type then check them for null before:

```
public static boolean isAccountHold(SubscriptionStatus subscription) {
    return subscription != null &&
            (subscription.isEntitlementActive == null || !subscription.isEntitlementActive) &&
            (subscription.isAccountHold != null || subscription.isAccountHold) &&
            !subscription.subAlreadyOwned;
}
```